# Can't send UDP packet with Infineon XMC 4500 RelaxKit

Tags: c, udp, lwip, infineon

i recently got an Infineon XMC4500 RelaxKit with an Ethernet Port to automate my house. I want to communicate from a server to the board (controlling different relays and such) through UDP. But i encountered an issue.

The board doesn't send anything, according to WireShark, but i can ping it successfully. Also, while pinging the board, the ethernet activity light doesn't flash at all, if that helps.

This is my code:

```
#include <DAVE.h>
int main(void)
{
    DAVE_Init();
    uint32_t button1;
    char str[512] = "Hello World!";
    ip_addr_t ip;
    ip.addr = 0xC0A8091;//192.168.0.145
    struct pbuf * pb;
    pb = pbuf_alloc(PBUF_TRANSPORT, 512, PBUF_REF);
    pb->payload = str;
    pb->len = pb->tot_len = 512;
    u16_t port = 5005;

    struct udp_pcb* pcb = udp_new();
    udp_connect(pcb, &ip, port);

    /* Placeholder for user application code. The while loop below can be replaced with user application code. */
    while(1U)
    {
        sys_check_timeouts();
        DIGITAL_IO_SetOutputLow(&DIGITAL_IO_0);
        button1 = DIGITAL_IO_GetInput(&DIGITAL_IO_1);
        if ( button1 == 1 ) {
            DIGITAL_IO_SetOutputLow(&DIGITAL_IO_0);
        }
        else {
            DIGITAL_IO_SetOutputHigh(&DIGITAL_IO_0);
            udp_send(pcb, pb);
        }
    }
}
```

The code is written in the DAVE IDE from Infineon.

Comment: is the posted code for the I/O board or for the server application?  What is the I/O board expecting to receive over ethernet?

Comment: the posted code seems to be trying to output the string `"Hello World!"`  to your controller board, repeatedly, while one of the buttons is pressed.   Does your controller board have any idea what to do with that string?

Comment: The I/O board(which has an Ethernet port)  is supposed to send a UDP packet to my computer (192.168.0.145) over Ethernet, the message being `Hello World!`.

Comment: the posted code turns some LED on/off but does not send anything to the Ethernet.  Suggest that be your next goal

Comment: ùdp_send(pcb, pb)` sends a packet over Ethernet. I have set to also light a led on a button press to know exactly that the function is firing.

Comment: the posted code not contain a call to `udp_send()` so the  call to `udp_send()` need to be added to your code.  inside the `while()` loop.  Probably inside the `if()` control block that turns the LED ON

Answer (score 1):

`ip.addr` should be `0x9100A8C0` for 192.168.0.145

Comment: Hello @Korvet, and welcome to SO. Your conversion is correct, but bytes are in the wrong order. It should read `c0.a8.00.91`. Maybe I'm rusty in IP addresses, but I don't remember any rule for inverting them. Could you have a look?

Comment: lwIP Macro: `IP4_ADDR(&ip, 192, 168, 0, 145);` Result: ip = `0x9100A8C0`